# Cleaning a column in a dataset R

Tags: r

So I got a dataset with a column that I need to clean.
The column has objects with stuff like: "*$10,000 - $19,999*", "*$40,000 and over*."

How do I code this so for example "$10,000 - $19,999" becomes 15000 instead, and "*$40,000 and over*" becomes 40000 in a new column?

I am new to R so I have no idea how to start. I need to do a regression analysis on this but it doesn't work if I don't get this fixed.

I have been told that some basic string/regex operations are what I need. How should I proceed?

Comment: [An introduction to `stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) is probably a good place to start.

Comment: Do you really need string manipulation? The column looks like a categorical variable, so if you know the category values, why not just use `ifelse()` or, even better, `dplyr::case_when()` to create a new column? Something along the lines of: `dplyr::case_when(df, col == "$0 - $4,999" ~ 2500, col == "$5,000 - $9,999" ~ 7500, col == "$10,000 - $19,999" ~ 15000, TRUE ~ 40000)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the `tidyverse`.

Load packages

```
library(dplyr) # for general cleaning functions
library(stringr) # for string manipulations
library(magrittr) # for the '%<>% function
```

Make a dummy dataset based on your example.

```
df <- data_frame(price = sample(c(rep('$40,000 and over', 10), 
                                  rep('$10,000', 10),
                                  rep('$19,999', 10),
                                  rep('$9,000', 10),
                                  rep('$28,000', 10))))
```

Inspect the new dataframe

```
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 50 x 1
#>    price           
#>    <chr>           
#>  1 $9,000          
#>  2 $40,000 and over
#>  3 $28,000         
#>  4 $10,000         
#>  5 $10,000         
#>  6 $9,000          
#>  7 $19,999         
#>  8 $10,000         
#>  9 $19,999         
#> 10 $40,000 and over
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

Clean-up the the format of the price strings by removing the `$` symbol and `,`. Note the use of the `'\\'` before the `$` symbol. This formatting is used within R to escape special characters (the second `\` is a standard regex escape switch, the first `\` is tells R to escape the second `\`).

```
df %<>% 
    mutate(price = str_remove(string = price, pattern = '\\$'), # remove $ sign
           price = str_remove(string = price, pattern = ',')) # remove comma
```

Quick check of the data.

```
head(df)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 1
#>   price         
#>   <chr>         
#> 1 9000          
#> 2 40000 and over
#> 3 28000         
#> 4 10000         
#> 5 10000         
#> 6 9000
```

Process the number strings into numerics. First convert `40000 and over` to `40000`, then convert all the strings to numerics, then use logic statements to convert the numbers to the values you want. The functions `ifelse()` and `case_when()` are interchangeable, but I tend to use `ifelse()` for single rules, and `case_when()` when there are multiple rules because of the more compact format of the `case_when()`.

```
df %<>%
    mutate(price = ifelse(price == '40000 and over', # convert 40000+ to 40000
                          yes = '40000',
                          no = price),
           price = as.numeric(price), # convert all to numeric
           price = case_when( # use logic statements to change values to desired value
               price == 40000 ~ 40000,
               price >= 30000 & price < 40000 ~ 35000,
               price >= 20000 & price < 30000 ~ 25000,
               price >= 10000 & price < 20000 ~ 15000,
               price >= 0 & price < 10000 ~ 5000
           ))
```

Have a final look.

````
print(df)
#> # A tibble: 50 x 1
#>    price
#>    <dbl>
#>  1  5000
#>  2 40000
#>  3 25000
#>  4 15000
#>  5 15000
#>  6  5000
#>  7 15000
#>  8 15000
#>  9 15000
#> 10 40000
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```
````

<sup>Created on 2018-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First you should see what exactly your data is composed of- use the table() function on data$column to see how many unique entries you must account for.

```
table(data$column)
```

If whoever was entering this data was consistent about their wording, it may be easiest to hard code for substitution for each unique entry. So if unique(data$column)[1]== "$10,000 - $19,999", and unique(data$column)[2]== "$40,000 and over."

```
data$column[which(data$column==unique(data$column)[1])] <- "15000"
data$column[which(data$column==unique(data$column)[2])] <- "40000"
...
```

If you have too many unique entries for this approach to be viable, I'd suggest looking for consistencies in character sequences that can be used to make replacements. If you found that whoever entered this data was inconsistent about how they would write "$40,000 and over" such that you had:

```
data$column==unique(data$column)[2]
>"$40,000 and over."
data$column==unique(data$column)[3]
>"$40,000 and over"
data$column==unique(data$column)[4]
>"above $40,000"
...
```

If there weren't instances of "$40,000" that belonged to other categories, you could combine these entries for substitution a la:

```
  data$column[which(grepl("$40,000",data$column))] <- "40000"
```

Inconsistency in qualitative data entry is a very human problem and requires exploring your data to search for trends and easy ways to consolidate your replacements. I think it's a fine idea to use R to identify and replace for patterns you find to save time, but ultimately it will require a fine touch as you get down to individual cases where you have to interpret/correct someone's entries to include them in your desired bins. Depending on your data quality standards, you can always throw out these entries that don't seem to fit your observed patterns.